# How to understand initial reference frame of iOS 8 device attitude？

Tags: ios, iphone, accelerometer, quaternions, core-motion

In apple developer document about Event Handling Guide for iOS we can find a statement “Core Motion establishes the reference frame when your app starts device-motion updates”.

1. Dose this means that when I start my app the first rotation data is my reference frame？
2. If this is true, when I start my app with any attitude the first set of quaternion should be [1 0 0 0], is this right ?

**Experiments about quaternion:**

1. **I start my app with iphone flat on the table**
     quaternion: [0.999 0.003 0.010 -0.004]
    accelerometer: [0.01 0.00 -1.00]
2. **I start my app with a tilt angle with X axis**
   quaternion: [0.97 0.22 0.000 0.000]
   accelerometer: [0.00 -0.44 -0.89]

The experiment results does not fit with the statement in the document. I'm really confused about it.

Comment: "the first set of quaternion should be [1 0 0 0], is this right" No, it isn't. —  What CMAttitudeReferenceFrame did you ask for when you began the updates?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did not manually set the CMAttitudeReferenceFrame constant. I just use the default value.

Comment: So what _is_ the default value? It is crucial to know what your reference frame is. This is a question _about_ the reference frame!

Comment: @matt I think the reference frame is the _CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical_ which describes a  reference frame in which the Z axis is vertical and the X axis points in an arbitrary direction in the horizontal plane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the reference frame CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical  when you are interested in *deviation from the initial position*. In a reference frame of CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical, the first attitude reported establishes the initial frame of reference. This means that its value is essentially arbitrary. You should ignore its value, but at the same time it is up to you to save this initial attitude and subsequently always to call `multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:` on any new attitudes, passing the saved attitude as parameter. This gives you information relative to the initial position.

Comment: Did you mean that I can set an attitude as initial reference frame by calling `multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:`, then all the reported attitudes are reference  to the attitude that I set ?

Comment: No, I mean what I said. You save the initial attitude and call `multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:` every time after that.

Comment: Same thing here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW14 "Cache the attitude object that contains the reference frame and pass it as the argument to `multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:`. The attitude argument receiving the message changes so that it represents the change in attitude from the passed-in reference frame."